# MVC 5 Enum in view - hide single element

Tags: c#, razor, view, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple status enum for email

```
public enum EmailStatus
{
    Current,
    Suspended,
    Cancelled,
    [Display(Name = "")]
    invalid
}
```

The flag invalid is set internally if the email can not be resolved.  I do not want that status to be shown in an edit field; users should be able to suspend or cancel an email but not set it to invalid.

Setting the display name to "" has no effect - invalid is still shown.  Is there a mechanism for this in razor or shall I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the option from the edit field data. For example:

```
var statuses = from EmailStatus s 
               in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EmailStatus)) 
               where s != EmailStatus.invalid
               select new { Id = s, Name = s.ToString() };
ViewBag.Statuses = new SelectList(statuses, "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: That is a neat answer; it matches the requirements at the expense of loosing the enum itself - I was hoping that there might be some form of decoration that could be used to supress the field.   If I do that I might also just have two enums - one internal and one for display purposes!